# How to add a search bar to pick sorted data from Picker view

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview, uisearchbar

Hi guys i have added a picker view to pick areas from it.This picker view contains more than 200 areas so it is difficult to scroll and select from picker view.

Is there any way to add a search bar and connect it with picker view?
I tried doing this by using search bar delegate method by overriding it but i am not able to achieve the goal.

So please help me so that i can do it or if any another way possible then also tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Picker view is for small number of selection. Use table view instead for such big number of options.

Just to back up my statement, the [Apple Human Interface Guideline](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW23) says

> Consider using a table view, instead of a picker, if you need to display a very large number of values. This is because the greater height of a table view makes scrolling faster."

Comment: Yeah bro you are right but the thing is that i have got the requirement to make it on picker view only.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with barley that the PickerView is an awful vehicle for large selections; if at all possible to use something else, that would be appropriate and best, but having said that:

The YHCPickerView looks promising from:

http://code4app.net/ios/PickerView-with-Search-Bar/509fb2e86803faf25c000000

From a cursory view of that class, it appears that it has several different and distinct UI elements, the text field for collecting search criteria, the button for enacting the search, and the basic picker view. The search criteria simply and directly filters the picker data/model when the button pressed event occurs. That way you are simply editing the actual data from the picker.

If you handle each of these separately it should make it simpler to create what you want, since you only have to handle the basic functions and delegates of each individual UI element and linking together their effects rather than trying to hijack an existing delegate.

-Cheers